# Buy only above middle band of bollinger bands

Tags: pine-script

I want to buy only above middle band of bollinger bands. Is `close > basis` alright, or should it be `close[1]`?

```
...

strategy(...

length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input(0, "Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)

...

buyCondition = ... and close > basis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need history reference for checking condition with the past data? (close[1]).

If not you just calculating condition it current bar, if it is true (close above basis) then you enter position.

like that

```
//@version=4
strategy("strategy", process_orders_on_close = true, overlay=true)


length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input(0, "Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)

plot(upper)
plot(lower)
plot(basis)

if (close>basis) 
    strategy.entry("EN", strategy.long)


if (close<lower) 
    strategy.close("EN")
```